# My Scroll View contents are not taking the full screen height?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have put some UI components on my scroll view, it's supposed to take the full height of the screen. but it's leaving some empty space at the bottom.[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show your tried code it is easy to optimize

Comment: what constraints did you add?

Answer (score 1):

it might be happen because of scroll view insets

try this:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

You can use Interface Builder also, just make sure `Adjust Scroll View Insets` option is not-checked

[image]